# Bash variable defaulting doesn't work if followed by pipe (bash bug?)

Tags: linux, bash

I've just discovered a strange behaviour in `bash` that I don't understand. The expression

```
${variable:=default}
```

sets `variable` to the value `default` if it isn't already set. Consider the following examples:

```
#!/bin/bash
file ${foo:=$1}
echo "foo >$foo<"
file ${bar:=$1} | cat
echo "bar >$bar<"
```

The output is:

```
$ ./test myfile.txt
myfile.txt: ASCII text
foo >myfile.txt<
myfile.txt: ASCII text
bar ><
```

You will notice that the variable `foo` is assigned the value of `$1` but the variable `bar` is not, even though the result of its defaulting is presented to the `file` command.

If you remove the innocuous pipe into `cat` from line 4 and re-run it, then it both `foo` and `bar` get set to the value of `$1`

Am I missing somehting here, or is this potentially a `bash` bug?

(GNU bash, version 4.3.30)

Comment: Most likely a bug, you should report it.

Comment: @ammoQ, nothing of the sort; documented behavior, and even part of the FAQ.

Comment: That's a `bash` *feature*, not a `bash` *bug*...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In second case `file` is a pipe member and runs as every pipe member in its own shell. When `file` with its subshell ends, `$b` with its new value from `$1` no longer exists.

Workaround:

```
#!/bin/bash
file ${foo:=$1}
echo "foo >$foo<"

: "${bar:=$1}"     # Parameter Expansion before subshell

file $bar | cat
echo "bar >$bar<"
```

Comment: Does that mean that parameter expansion is performed in the subshell instead of before the subshell is created?

Comment: @starfry: chepner explained it properly in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a bug. Parameter expansion happens when the command is evaluated, not parsed, but a command that is part of a pipeline is not evaluated until the new process has been started. Changing this, aside from likely breaking some existing code, would require extra level of expansion *before* evaluation occurs.

A hypothetical `bash` session:

```
> foo=5
> bar='$foo'
> echo "$bar"
$foo
# $bar expands to '$foo' before the subshell is created, but then `$foo` expands to 5
# during the "normal" round of parameter expansion.
> echo "$bar" | cat
5
```

To avoid that, `bash` would need some way of marking pieces of text that result from the new first round of pre-evaluation parameter expansion, so that they do not undergo a second
round of evaluation. This type of bookkeeping would quickly lead to unmaintainable code as more corner cases are found to be handled. Far simpler is to just accept that parameter expansions will be deferred until after the subshell starts.

The other alternative is to allow each component to run in the current shell, something that is allowed by the POSIX standard, but is not required, either. `bash` made the choice long ago to execute each component in a subshell, and reversing that would break too much existing code that relies on the current behavior. (`bash` 4.2 did introduce the `lastpipe` option, allowing the *last* component of a pipeline to execute in the current shell if explicitly enabled.)

Comment: On my bash version 4.3.30, `echo "$bar" | cat` results in `$foo` being printed, not `5`.

Comment: Yes; the example I showed is hypothetical, not representing any real version of bash, to demonstrate the extra work bash would need to do to avoid such double expansion if parameters were expanded in the current shell.